# Database design. Is trinary relationship the only way?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, constraints, relationship

I have the following database schema that I have come up with:

Tables:

employees(id_pk, name)

employees_attend_at_service_desk(employee_id_pk_fk, service_desk_id_pk_fk not null) references employee and service_desk

service_desk(id_pk, name, shop_id_fk not null) references shop

works(employee_id_pk_fk,shop_id_pk_fk not null) references shop and employee

shop(id_pk, company_id_fk not null)

company(id_pk, name)

This database will be queried from a website and from a desktop app.

So take this example into account: shop 1 has service_desk 1 and 2 and shop 2 has service_desk 3. Employee 1 works only in shop 1.

I want to attribute a service_desk from shop 1 to employee 1, but I want to add some sort of constraint that won't allow me to add service_desk 3 for example because that service desk belongs to shop 2 and employee 1 works only in shop 1. Is a trinary relationship the only way to get what I require when considering database design?

What I have thought on doing is to query the DB to get all of shop 1's employees and then query the DB again to find out the shop's service_desks.
Then I can distribute the employees of shop 1 into there respective service_desks.

Doing it this way means the database isn't very robust? Or is this design ok? And My app can take care of the constraints I need?

Thanks a lot in advance to all!

Comment: You may be interested in reading about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_normal_form

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to that article. Did you point me to that article because I am breaking up my DB schema into to many tables? And perhaps instead of having so many entities I could have less? Like for example instead of having a service_desk I could perhaps do something like this? employee(id_pk, name, service_desk_number)... Thanks once again!

Comment: No, just that there's a relational theory background to the enforcement rule you're trying to implement. And you shouldn't believe people who claim that rules of normalization above 3rd normal form are not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to:

1. add `shop_id_pk_fk` to `employees_attend_at_service_desk`
2. Add a foreign key `employees_attend_at_service_desk (shop_id_fk)` referencing `shop (id_pk_)`
3. Create a unique key in `service_desk (id_pk, shop_id_fk`. (Required for step 4).
4. Add foreign key to `employees_attend_at_service_desk (service_desk_id_pk_fk, shop_id_fk)` referencing `service_desk (id_pk, shop_id_fk)` to ensure a valid shop is entered for the service desk.
5. Add a foreign key `employees_attend_at_service_desk (employee_id_pk_fk, shop_id_fk)` referencing `works (employee_id_pk_fk, shop_id_pk_fk)`

This will duplicate some data, but only one int column, and will mean that you can build the requisite constraints to ensure you have a valid employee on a service desk.

You could also leave the validation up to your app. I don't think it is particularly bad practice either way.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for taking the time to answering my question.
But on step 1 won't that create a trinary relationship?
Because buy adding shop_id_pk_fk to employees_attend_at_service_desk, I'll have:


employees_attend_at_service_desk(employee_id_pk_fk, service_desk_id_pk_fk not null, shop_id_pk_fk) references employee and service_desk and shop ... right?

Comment: Yes and no. It has 3 underlying relationships in `service_desk` and `shop` and `employee`, but these are not the only limitations. They aren't even required (but still a good idea). The composite keys referencing `service_desk` and `works` do the heavy lifting here, and are the only required relationships, e.g. [Example on db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bPYM3gAJ1AezebC5nQ1Jp8/0). So yes, there are 3 underlying relationships, but there are only two that matter.

Comment: You don't strictly need the foreign key defined in step 2. By the foreign key you add in step 4, you can only reference valid pairs of service desks and shops, and the service desk table will naturally still have a foreign key to shop, ensuring the shop id's are valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GarethD.
I will accept your answer as it has helped me further in understanding the whole problem at hand. Possibly I will use my app to validate the constraints I need as it will reduce the complexity of the database.